# How to prevent Entity Framework from creating double Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

i'm having trouble with creating a database from my entities using code first. Please consider the two classes. CourseTn class

```
    public class CourseTn
{
    // Pk
    public CourseLevel CourseTnId { get; set; }

    // Properties
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual List<CourseTnImage> CourseImage { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ChapterTn> Chapters { get; set; }

    public AdministratorTnAccount AdministratorTnAccount { get; set; }
    public Guid? AdministratorTnAccountId { get; set; }

    public ClientTnAccount ClientTnAccount { get; set; }
    public Guid? ClientTnAccountId { get; set; }

}
```

and the ChapterTn class

```
public class ChapterTn
{
    // Pk
    public int ChapterTnId { get; set; }

    // Properties
    public string ChapterName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ChapterTnImage> ChapterImage { get; set; }
    public virtual List<SectionTn> Sections { get; set; }

    // FK

    public virtual CourseTn CourseTn { get; set; }
    public CourseLevel CourseTnId { get; set; }
}
```

The courseTnId is specified within the chapterTn class as a foreign key. The first issue is that the Entitiy Framework doesnt seem to recorgnis this convention, and maps courseTnId as a proptery instead.

The second issue is that the Enitity Framework creates two FK for the courseTn, one is null and the other is not null. Please see bellow image

[image]

Is there a way to make make Entity Framework recognise the conventional specified FK of courseTnId in the chapterTn class ?

Comment: why would your PK of courseTn be the type of CourseLevel and not int?

Comment: You can use, ForeignKeyAttribute and InversePropertyAttribute, or alternatively you can use ModelBuilder to set the relation with FluentAPI. Have you tried those options.

Answer (score 0):

Your PK can't be complex type `CourseLevel`. And same for your FK. Try the below:

```
    public class CourseTn
    {
        // Pk
        public int CourseTnId { get; set; }

        // Properties
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual List<CourseTnImage> CourseImage { get; set; }
        public virtual List<ChapterTn> Chapters { get; set; }

        public AdministratorTnAccount AdministratorTnAccount { get; set; }
        public Guid? AdministratorTnAccountId { get; set; }

        public ClientTnAccount ClientTnAccount { get; set; }
        public Guid? ClientTnAccountId { get; set; }

    }

    public class ChapterTn
    {
        // Pk
        public int ChapterTnId { get; set; }

        // Properties
        public string ChapterName { get; set; }
        public virtual List<ChapterTnImage> ChapterImage { get; set; }
        public virtual List<SectionTn> Sections { get; set; }

        // FK
        public virtual CourseTn CourseTn { get; set; }
        public int CourseTnId { get; set; }
    }
```

You can additionally force FK recognition with attribute on `CourseTnId` in your `ChapterTn` class.
`[ForeignKey("CourseTn"), Column(Order = 0)]`

Comment: Hi Vidmantas, thanks for the reply. The courseLevel datatype of the courseTn primary key is actually an enum, and not a complex type. Doesn't Entity Framework automatically map type enum to type int ?

Comment: @Ntu You still can't have primary key as enum because that only gives you a finite number of possible primary keys to use. If you use enum then that finite number will be number of enum options. The mapping to an enum should work if it was not a primary key column or FK.

Answer (score 0):

You planned to design a one-to-many relationship between `Course` and `Chapter`: every `Course` has zero or more `Chapters`, every `Chapter` belongs to exactly one `Course`.

For some reason you decided to deviate from [the entity framework code-first conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx), thus obliging you to correct this using attributes or fluent API.

Why are your "to-many" collection classes Lists instead of ICollections? Does `Course.Chapters[4]` really mean something? Besides, are you sure that you want to limit yourself to Courses with real Lists of Chapters? No of course not, because internally your Course does not even have a List of chapters. Internally there are two tables with foreign keys and such. So it isn't a List. It is at utmost a thing where you can Add an element, and can ask for the number of Elements: not a List, but an ICollection.

For some reason the type of the primary key of your Courses is a CourseLevel. Are you sure that in your design it is unthinkable that two Courses might have the same CourseLevel? And are you sure, that before adding a Course to your database you don't know its CourseLevel? Will a Course never get harder or easier, and thus changes its CourseLevel? What benefit did you get by trying to do some tricky things with the database identifiers?

Furthermore, and I think that is the cause of your problem: although you give your chapters a value `CourseId` you forget to tell entity framework that this is the foreign key to the Course of the chapter.

The following is really enough to solve all your problems.

```
class Course
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    // every Course has zero or more Chapters:
    public virtual ICollection<Chapter> Chapters {get; set;}

    // other properties:
    public CourseLevel Level {get; set;}
    ...
}

class Chapter
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every Chapter belongs to exactly one Course using foreign key
    public int CourseId {get; set;}
    public virtual Course Course {get; set;}

    ... // other properties
}
```

Because I followed [the entity framework one-to-many conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx), this is all entity framework needs to know to configure the two tables and the primary and foreign key. No attributes, nor fluent API is needed.

I also changed the primary key to a more conventional type, if you really have good arguments to keep it your way, try it and see if it works.